# Issue using jquery animate()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have two issues:

1. Having a problem with Jquery's `animate()` not working smoothly on Chrome, Safari and Opera. The `Jquery` `animate()`function works fine in Firefox but does not run smoothly using the other browsers(Just pops up as opposed to raising smoothly)
2. When I click the button to activate the div it moves up but when I click to return the div to its normal state to slide back down, it does not work.

Any suggestions with rewriting my code/logic? Thank You!

**Html:**

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="icons-portfolio/foundation-icons/foundation-icons.css">
    <!--  CSS for resets  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css">
    <!--  CSS for other styles  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/components.css">

    <!--*****Need JS Libraries in head ************ -->
    <!--<script src="js/modernizr.custom.38675.js"></script>-->
    <script src="js/modernizr.custom.79941.js"></script>

    <!--
    This script enables structural HTML5 elements in old IE.
    http://code.google.com/p/html5shim/ -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src = "//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->    
  </head>
    <body>

    <!-- Part 1: Wrap all page content here -->
    <div class="wrap"> 
      <header>
        <div>
          <h1 class="mainHeadNav">CSS3 Effects 'N Stuff</h1>
        </div>
        <a href="https://github.com/Amechi101/css3effects"><img style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; border: 0;" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/github/ribbons/forkme_right_green_007200.png" alt="Fork me on GitHub"></a>
      </header> 

      <!-- grid -->
      <main class="grid_main">  
        <section class="userBox">
        <div>
          <figure class="user_photo_container">
            <figcaption class="user_name">
              <span>Menu</span>
            </figcaption>
          </figure>
          <ul class="user_inner" id="main-dash">
            <li><a href="https://amechi-egbe.squarespace.com/css3-effects">Back to Portfolio<i class="fi-photo"></i></a></li> 
            <li><a  href="https://www.facebook.com/amechi.egbe">Facebook<i class="fi-social-facebook"></i></a></li>  
            <li><a href="https://twitter.com/FashionIdealist">Twitter<i class="fi-social-twitter"></i></a></li> 
            <li><a href="http://instagram.com/fashion_idealist">Instagram<i class="fi-social-instagram"></i></a></li>
            <li><a id="dashClick" href="#">Dashboard<i class="fi-page"></i></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        </section>

        <section class="boxFeatures box1">
          <div   class="inspire">
            <h2>Transition</h2> 
          </div>
        </section>

        <section class="boxFeatures box2">
            <div class="inspire">
              <h2>Hover & Scale</h2> 
            </div>
        </section>

        <section class="boxFeatures box3">
            <div class="inspire">
              <h2>Sideways Flip</h2>  
            </div>
        </section>

        <section class="boxFeatures box4">
            <div class="inspire">
              <h2>3D</h2>  
            </div>
        </section>

      <!-- Dashboard start -->
        <div id="Dashboard"> 
          <h2 class="dashTitle">Project Information</h2>
          <div class="dashInnerAdd">
            <p>
              Welcome to my project CSS3 Effects N' Stuff! I started this project to develop different cool effects using the new CSS3 Properties. Feel free to fork over the repository and contribute! If you like the project and want to chat email me: <a href="mailto:amechiegbe@gmail.com" target="_top">amechiegbe@gmail.com</a>
            </p> 
          </div> 
        </div>
      </main>  <!-- end grid main-->
    </div> <!--end wrap -->

    <!-- Le javascript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/application.js"></script>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(function() {
    //Modernizer Test
    Modernizr.addTest("keyframe", Modernizr.testAllProps('animationName'));
    Modernizr.prefixed('requestAnimationFrame', window, true);

    // global functions
    var dash = $('#Dashboard');
    var dashBtn = $('#dashClick');
    var clicked = false;

    dashBtn.on('click',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if(clicked === true || clicked === false) {
            dash.animate({"top":0}, 400, function () {
                console.log('Up');
            });
        } else {
            clicked = true;
            dash.animate({"top":600}, 400, function () {
                console.log('Down');
            });
        }
    });

    //make it height of document
    dash.document.height();
});
```

Comment: It's kind of hard to suggest edits to your code when you haven't posted it for us to see...

Comment: LOL "Any suggestions with rewriting my code?" and no code is exposed!

Comment: Whoops! That is kind of embarrassing on my part! Sorry about that!

Comment: Are you sure this is a jQuery issue and not a Modernizr issue?

Comment: "if(clicked === true || clicked === false)" when this if won't have a true return?

Comment: @jraede am using the development version of modernizr so it should have everything I would need regardless I believe unless, I need to specifically write code for my issue to use with mordenizr?

Comment: So what browser does it work in, first it works smoothly in many browsers, then it works in firefox but not other browsers ?

Comment: And one has to wonder, what exactly is `$('#Dashboard')`, and why on earth would it have a `document` property ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without your code it is hard to see which effect you are using or how you are easing it.  You can use the properties of .animate to change the way it runs smoothly.
https://api.jquery.com/animate/

```
.animate( properties [, duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )
```

The default easing is Swing.

I would say to try linear... to me that is more "smooth".
http://api.jqueryui.com/easings/